# rational points on particular elliptic curve

Tags: diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

I do have a few books that discuss elliptic curves, however...

What are the rational points on 
$$  y^2 = 4 x^3 - 4 x = 4 x(x-1)(x+1)?  $$ 
I think it ought to be  $(-1,0), (0,0), (1,0).$ Maybe it's just me. I also think this must be a famous first case, written in some popular book I don't have. 
I do not think there is any important difference if you prefer
$$ w^2 = v^3 - v.  $$ The curve in the real plane has two connected components.

If this works the way I want it will finish [There is no Pythagorean triple in which the hypotenuse and one leg are the legs of another Pythagorean triple.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696629/there-is-no-pythagorean-triple-in-which-the-hypotenuse-and-one-leg-are-the-legs/696888#696888)

Comment: These are indeed the only rational points of this curve, but I’m unfortunately not in a position to give you a reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be integers, and let $E_{A,B}: y^2=x^3+Ax^2+Bx$ be an elliptic curve. Then, the rank of the Mordell-Weil group $E_{A,B}(\mathbb{Q})$ is less or equal to $\nu(A^2-4B)+\nu(B)-1$, where $\nu(N)$ is the number of positive prime divisors of $N$. This is shown in Milne's "[Elliptic Curves](http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ectext5.pdf)", Proposition 5.6, or [here (Proposition 1.1)](http://alozano.clas.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/2014/01/ALP-2-23-07.pdf).

In particular, $E_{0,-1}:y^2=x^3-x$ has rank less or equal to $1+0-1=0$, and so the rank is $0$. The torsion subgroup can be shown to be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so $E_{0,-1}(\mathbb{Q})=\{\infty, (0,0),(1,0),(-1,0)\}.$

By the way, notice that the natural number $n$ is [a congruent number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number) if and only if the elliptic curve $E: y^2=x^3-n^2x$ is a curve of rank $0$. The proof that $n=1$ is not a congruent number is due to Fermat, and it is `elementary'. The proof can be found in [these notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/congnumber.pdf), Theorem 2.1, by Keith Conrad.

Comment: @WillJagy, in the new edited version, I added a note about an "elementary" proof of the fact that the rank of $y^2=x^3-x$ is zero.

Comment: Oooh, paragraph just before Example 4.3: "For example, since $1$ is not congruent (Theorem 2.1), the only rational solutions to $y^2 = x^3 - x$ have $y=0.$"