# Do there exist any Pythagorean triples that share two out of three numbers?

Tags: diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

The following question occurred to me while sketching out vector diagrams earlier today:  Do there exist positive integers $a, b, c, d$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and $a^2 - b^2 = d^2$?  In other words, do there exist any Pythagorean triples that share a "leg", and for which the "leg" of one is the "hypotenuse" of the other?  If not, can it be proven that such triples do not exist?

**What I've tried:** I've played around a bit with Euclid's formula, and it's easy enough to show that if such a pair of triples exists, it must be the case that there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$$
d^2 = m^4 - 6 m^2 n^2 + n^4
$$
is a perfect square.  ($m$ and $n$ are the integers on which the triple $(a,b,c)$ is based.)  Similarly, if the triple $(a,d,b)$ is based on the integers $m'$ and $n'$, we end up with
$$
c^2 = 2\left({m'}^4 + {n'}^4\right)
$$
This latter equation looks a little more plausible as something that doesn't have integer solutions.  But I don't really know where to go from here, or even if this is the best way to think about it.

Comment: See also: [Are there any positive integers $a, b, c, d$ such that both $(a, b, c)$ and $(b, c, d)$ are Pythagorean triples?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/960816) and [Is there $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb N$ so that $a^2+b^2=c^2$, $b^2+c^2=d^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1146460)

Answer (score 0):

This is Fermat's right triangle theorem, since $a^2-b^2,a^2,a^2+b^2$ would form an arithmetic progression with common difference a square.